# Undo a homebrew cleanup

Tags: python-2.7, homebrew

I was trying to install something with `homebrew` and it appears it automatically did a cleanup and removed `Python2`. It's deprecated but I currently need `python2` for some things that still depend on `pyhon2`.

How can I undo this move?

Comment: Note you don’t need Homebrew to have Python 2, it’s already provided in macOS.

Comment: command not found: python2 on the terminal

Comment: Does `python --version` show Python 2?

Comment: no it shows `Python 3`, I've reinstalled `python 2` and will reinstall each package I need again. I will need to disable this automatic cleanup of `homebrew` to prevent it happening again.